# Raspberry Pi Imager can't use Ubuntu Server Image

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi-imager

With the *Raspberry Pi 3B*, *Raspberry Pi Imager*, *Ubuntu Server 64bit 23.04*, for writing the SD card image, I tried the following Imager options:

At Image Customization Options Tried:

- No configuration at all
- Set Hostname: `host`
- Set username and password: `user`, `pssw`, Disable SSH
- Set username and password: `user`, `pssw`, Enable SSH Use Password Authentication

Hardware configuration:

- Using a Mouse, Keyboard, Monitor, and LAN Cable connected

I gave a try to the "Raspberry PI Imager" from [raspberrypi.com](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/). It couldn't be easier than simply flashing an image from [ubuntu.com](https://www.ubuntu.com). But I gave it a try.

After about 10 different trials, and 4 hours, the fancy "Raspberry Pi Imager", and waiting all those minutes you want to wait after the processes ended, the installation got stuck in the login prompt, and no possible configured user/pssw are accepted, with or without an SSH access, such as:

Username and Password Options Tried:

- `ubuntu` `ubuntu`
- `ubuntu` `<Blank>`
- `<Set Device Name>` `<Blank>`
- `<Set Device Name>` `<Set Device Name>`
- `<Set Username>` `<Set Password>`
- `<Set Username>` `<Blank>`
- `pi` `raspberry`
- `pi` `admin`

Error at SSH Prompt:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.2
user@192.168.1.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Error at Login Prompt:

```
Ubuntu 23.04 host tty1
host login:
password:
Login Incorrect
```

For some absurd reason, the Raspberry Pi Imager is messing with the Ubuntu Image and making it non-functional.

**Solution so far:**

Hours lost giving a cent to a piece of crap.

**Don't mess with the cute Imager. Go straight to the source ubuntu.com and burn it with BalenaEtcher (Not with Rufus!). Then SSH with ubuntu/ubuntu**

Problem solved.

Comment: Ubuntu (like most Linux OS) requires you to create a user on first boot. The imager installs OS but the shortcuts are only for Raspberry Pi OS because the other OS **don't have the code required to implement them**. If you used a keyboard & monitor it would have worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is with the cute Raspberry PI Imager.

Don't use it if you go the Ubuntu way.

**Go straight to the source ubuntu.com** and burn it with BalenaEtcher (Not with Rufus!).

Then SSH with ubuntu/ubuntu.

Problem Solved.